# Priority language in multi language website

Tags: asp.net, resources, default, multilingual, hindi

I'm following this guide to create a multi language page : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334820/Using-Globalization-and-Localization-in-ASP-NET
But a problem is :
I want my website default language is Hindi. 
But the browser often set English is default language. That cause when I load my site, the language on it is English, not Hindi (I change resx file in Hindi to default.aspx.resx and change English resx file to default.aspx.en-US.resx but the browser still display English).
How can I set default my website default language is Hindi ?

Code :

default.aspx :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblWelcome" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblWelcomeResource1"
        Text="Welcome to Learning"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="hi-in">हिंदी</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="en-us">English</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblNotice" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblNoticeResource1" Text="Today is:"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblTimeResource1"></asp:Label></div>
</form>
```

Default.aspx.cs :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}

protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Request.Form["DropDownList1"] != null)
    {
        UICulture = Request.Form["DropDownList1"];
        Culture = Request.Form["DropDownList1"];
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Resx file in Hindi is : Default.aspx.resx and Resx file in English is Default.aspx.en-US.resx

Thanks and sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to override the default behaviour is to set the culture programmatically like in Application_OnStart in `Global.asax`, this function will run once for every new unique session.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: I added that code to Global.asax. And Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture on Global.asax = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = hi-IN but Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture on default.aspx still = en-US. How can I call session Culture from Global to default.aspx (defalt.aspx is not using a masterpage)

Comment: Please provide us with your code and I'll have a look. The better you describe what you have tried to do, researched and encountered, the easier it is to give you a correct answer.

Comment: I create a new page with a webform default.aspx like my question.
I'd create a global.asax and add :
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>

<script runat="server">
    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    }
</script>
2 files resx : default.aspx.resx in Hindi and default.aspx.en-US.resx in Eng.
That's all